# Python: How to send changing message with discord.py/py-cord?

Tags: python, discord.py, pycord

How can I send a later on changing message?

I tried something like this:

```
message = bot.get_channel(id).send("deleting in 5s")
time.sleep(5)
message.delete()
```

But it gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'edit'
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Where is the `edit` part in the code though? Also: `time.sleep()` is outdated and should not be used anymore, use `asyncio.sleep()` instead.

Comment: pycord != discord.py. Please remove one of the two tags.

Comment: Please include the full traceback of the error and the part of the code where it happens (it should give you some line numbers).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`send`, `delete` and `edit` are async functions, remember to use await when calling them.

```py
channel = bot.get_channel(id)
message = await channel.send("deleting in 5s")
time.sleep(5)
await message.delete()
```